# Open Source C++ XML Data Binding tool/libary with non (L)GPL license?

Tags: open-source, c++, xml

I've googled extensively for such a tool/library and searched through Stack Overflow, but all I found are (L)GPL or proprietary licensed ones.

The company I'm working for is specifically looking for an Open Source, non (L)GPL, XML Data Binding tool and/or library that produces C++ code, better if in the same style as [xsd from CodeSynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) does. Does it exist at all, as far as you know?

Comment: If you don't want (L)GPL nor Proprietary which licence(s) __are__ acceptable?

Comment: Apache, BSD, MIT, any that allows redistributing the binary without any implication on redistribution of the source code.

Comment: It would be a good idea to specify that in your question.

Comment: It is also worth noting that LGPL allows redistribution of the unmodified binary you simply cannot modify the LGPL component without publishing the source for that modified component. So if there is a LGPG component that does what you need you can redistribute a binary containing it but if you fix bugs in or enhance that component you have to offer the source _of the modified LGPL component_.

Comment: If you find one I'm very interesting. there are some tools like codesynthesis where you can by a license so you get out of the the GPL or LGPL. but basically a lot of these tools do not fit either they are not 100% compliant to the xml standard or have some tweaks or limitations that make them unfit. - what I'm considering is to write my own. basically you need to cover some items - need to create a basic model in C++ from e.g. xsd schema or from uml - implement this model by creating a class implementation of this model - the two steps above can be done at once using modern C++ (remove the in